# How to make my previous queston active

Tags: support

I posted a question and I didnt get answer. Now I want to repost or make it active so that I can try my luck if I can get answer this time from the forum. How to proceed ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit your question, it will get bumped up to the top of the list again.

Comment: I followed as you said and I got a message as "This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.". What are the chances of my question to be active? If not, whats my next step as I am desperately looking a program/script from form as i am very poor in programming.

Comment: Another solution is to offer a bounty, it appears you have enough rep to do so.

Comment: @prasad The problem is that you lost ownership of the question when you created a new user account.

Comment: I am not able to look the question under my profile. When I am new I saw many members having accounts in gis and others....By seeing that, I was in an impression that I need to create accounts in which ever form I want. but at that time I got message that no need to create account. So I didn't created another account. Pls clear me, do I have two accounts now? If no, How can I resolve the problem. I want to see all my questions under my profile. Ans also for today's edit, I got badge as organizer but the question was not active .I didn't see in newest questions. Pls suggest.

Comment: I saw the question in active list now.

Comment: @prasad I merged your accounts. Everything should be fine now.